# How do I finish this trig integral $\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos \theta}d\theta$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I got up to the part where it's $$\frac{9}{125}\int_0^{\large \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos\theta}\,\,d\theta$$

but I can't figure out how to finish it off.

By the way the original problem was:

$$\int_0^{0.6}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9-25x^2}}\,\,dx$$

Comment: Try using the fact that $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$.

Comment: I think you forgot to substitute for dx in the integral.

Answer (score 3):

Your substitution is a bit off. Begin with

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{0.6}{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9-25x^2}}}\, dx
&= \int_0^{0.6}{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{25\left(\frac{9}{25}-x^2\right)}}}\, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{5}\int_0^{0.6}{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{\frac{9}{25}-x^2}}}\, dx.
\end{align*}
$$

Now let 
$$\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{3}{5}\sin \theta \\
dx&=\frac{3}{5}\cos\theta \, d \theta. \\
x^2&=\frac{9}{25}\sin^2\theta, \\
\frac{9}{25}-x^2&=\frac{9}{25}-\frac{9}{25}\sin^2\theta\\
&=\frac{9}{25}\cos^2\theta.
\end{align*}
$$

To change limits, note that when $x=0$, $\frac{3}{5}\sin \theta=0\Rightarrow \theta=0$, but when $x=0.6=\frac{3}{5}$, $\frac{3}{5}\sin \theta=\frac{3}{5}\Rightarrow \sin\theta=1 \Rightarrow \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

So your integral is now

$$\frac{1}{5}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\frac{9}{25}\sin^2\theta\frac{3}{5}\cos \theta}{\sqrt{\frac{9}{25}\cos^2\theta}}\, d \theta.$$

I'll let you pick it up from there.

Answer (score 1):

You may observe that, with $u=\sin \theta$, we have
$$
\int_0^{\large \pi/4}\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos \theta}d\theta=\int_0^{\large \pi/4}\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}\cos \theta \:d\theta=\int_0^{ \sqrt{2}/2}\frac{u^2 }{1-u^2} \:du=\log(\sqrt{2}+1)-\frac{\sqrt{2}}2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the trick to add and remove a $\cos^2\theta$ term in the numerator of the integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta - \cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta}\ \text{d}\theta = \int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{\cos\theta} - \cos\theta\ \text{d}\theta$$

Which now you can split.

Remembering that $$\frac{1}{\cos\theta} = \text{sec}(\theta)$$

you have immediately, by remembering standard integral of the secant:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\text{sec}\theta\ \text{d}\theta = \left[\ln\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2} - \sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right) + \ln\left(\cos\frac{\theta}{2} + \sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right]\bigg|_0^{\pi/4} = \frac{1}{2}\ln(3 + 2\sqrt{2})$$

The other one is trivial:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos\theta\ \text{d}\theta = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Thence:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{1}{\cos\theta} - \cos\theta\ \text{d}\theta = \frac{1}{2}\ln(3 + 2\sqrt{2}) - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$